# Gold Badge does not appears in Mobile View

Tags: bug, design, duplicate-questions, close-dialog

I came through a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62977590/10961238) that has been closed as a duplicate by a golden badge owner. While viewing from mobile the Golden Badge does not display correctly as we can see in the web view.

**Mobile View**
[image]

**Web View**

[image]

Comment: Mobile view hasn't been supported in years... Use the responsive view of the site on your mobile device. You can find a link to switch in the footer.